# How to open html file in default browser in JDK 1.4

Tags: java, browser, jdk1.4

I see a lot of JDK 1.6 notes about how to open an HTML file in the default browser but none for JDK 1.4.

Does anyone have any experience with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[browserlaunch2](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/) has worked for me in the past.

Comment: *"browserlaunch2 has worked for me in the past."*  Me as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same code as in version 1.6, just add a reference to [JDesktop integration](http://java.net/projects/jdic) jar. I think (but I'm not 100% sure) this is actually the same library you get with Java 1.6, it was developed as a separate project by Sun before they include in Jdk 1.6.